# switchIfEmpty executed when the prior flatMap returns Mono.error()

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring gateway filter that has analogues code:

```java
public Mono<Something> example {
    return redisTemplate.opsForValue()
        .get(cacheKey)
        .flatMap(this::throwMono)        
        .switchIfEmpty(somethingElse(cacheKey, token));
}
private Mono<Something> throwMono(String jsonString) {
    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("oops"));
}
```

I thought this will result in flow ending at exception but `switchIfEmpty` is always run when an exception occurs.

I expect `Mono.error()` to be returned and `switchIfEmpty` to not run in case of exception in `flatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Mono.error is actually returned. `somethingElse` method is run just because you explicitly call it, but returned Mono is not subscribed nor executed.

Consider a modified example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mono.just("initial")
            .flatMap(s -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("oops")))
            .switchIfEmpty(somethingElse())
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println("Success: " + s), Throwable::printStackTrace);
}

private static Mono<String> somethingElse() {
    System.out.println("somethingElse run");
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                System.out.println("run else Mono");
                return "else";
            })
            .doOnSubscribe(c -> System.out.println("else Mono subscribed"));
}
```

ends with

> run somethingElse 
> java.lang.RuntimeException: oops  
> ...

There is no "run else Mono", "else Mono subscribed" or "Success"

Comment: The output of the function that I only added return statement of, is being used in spring cloud gateway filter factory, I am using a flatMap to get the return value and mutate the exchange. I don't think I can put subscribe in the middle of this flow?

Comment: subscribe is put here just to run reactive stream instead of spring. Example shows that Mono from somethingElse is actually doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you may confused about the reactive execution .  the method in  `switchIfEmpty` should return a Mono value , so  actually , in wrapper the mono into a method , but if there some logic out of reactive scope , it must be execute , if you would like to handle all of them  in reactive  lifecycle , you should  add you logic into Mono reactive execution chain.

```java
    private static Mono<String> somethingElse() {
        System.out.println("out of reactive scope"); // so  it would be executed
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                    System.out.println("inside of reactive scope"); // Lazy until  subscrible
                    return "reactor";
                })
               ;
    }
```